# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Not" while fetching when I add JWT auth header

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, redux, jwt

I am currently working on a react-native money transfer full-stack app using react-native and redux for client-side and node for the server. I am having a problem with authenticating all requests with JWT token while dispatching server calls from action creators. I have multiple endpoints like (signIn, signUp, make-Transfer, get-recent-user...) and more.

my singIn and signUp API calls are working perfectly with auth header, while all other API calls are failing with auth header (JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Not" while fetching {the endpoint}) and succeeding without auth header. as of now, I think the problem is coming from the server. maybe from the JWT middleware function. here is the code I am working with to get a better understanding.

userActions.js

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { IS_USER, ADD_ERROR } from '../constants';
import fetchRequest from '../api/apiFetch';

export const isUserAction = phoneNumber => async dispatch => {
  const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
  const userToken = JSON.parse(userData);
  const { token } = userToken.token;
  const user = await fetchRequest(`/isUser/${phoneNumber}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });

  if (user) {
    dispatch(checkUser(user));
  } else {
    dispatch(addError(user));
  }
};

const checkUser = userData => ({
  type: IS_USER,
  payload: userData
});

const addError = error => ({
  type: ADD_ERROR,
  payload: 'something went wrong'
});
```

apiFetch.js

```
const fetchRequest = async (url, options) => {
  try {
    const req = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}${url}`, options);
    const res = req.status <= 404 ? req : Promise.reject(req);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`${e.message} while fetching ${url}`);
  }
};

export default fetchRequest;
```

server.js

```
const koa = require('koa');
const app = new koa();
const cors = require('@koa/cors');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const config = require('./config/config');
const router = require('./router');
const models = require('./models/db');
const jwt = require('./middleware/jwt');

app
  .use(cors())
  .use(bodyParser())
  .use(jwt)
  .use(router.routes());

(async function () {
  try {
    await models.sequelize.sync();
    app.listen(config.PORT, () => {
      console.log(`server running on  ${config.PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('unable to connect to the database', error);  
  }
})();
```

JWT.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const models = require('../models/db');

module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  const authorization = ctx.request.headers.authorization;
  const url = ctx.url.split('/')[1];


  if (!authorization && url !== 'signUp') {
    ctx.body = {
      message: 'no auth provided'
    };
    ctx.status = 401;
  }

  if (authorization) {
    const tokenHead = authorization.split(' ');
    if (tokenHead[0] !== 'Bearer') {
      return await next();
    } else {
      const token = authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');

      jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, payload) => {
        if (err) {
          ctx.status = 401;
          ctx.body = {
            message: 'Failed to authenticate token'
          };
        }
        const { userId } = payload;

        const user = await models.User.findOne({ where: { id: userId } });
        ctx.user = user;
        next();
      });
    }
  } else await next();
};
```

userController.js

```
const models = require('../models/db');

exports.isUser = async ctx => {
  try {
    const phoneNumber = Number(ctx.params.phoneNumber);
    const user = await models.User.findOne({
      where: {
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber
      }
    });

    if (user) {
      console.log('reached here');
      ctx.body = {
        data: {
          id: user.dataValues.id,
          phoneNumber: user.dataValues.phoneNumber
        },
        isUser: true
      };
      console.log("TCL: ctx.body", ctx.body)
      ctx.status = 200;
    } else {
      ctx.body = {
        message: 'user not found',
        isUser: false
      };
      console.log("TCL: ctx.body", ctx.body)
      ctx.status = 204;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    ctx.body = {
      status: 'unsuccessful',
      message: 'something went wrong',
      error: error
    };
    ctx.status = 406;
  }
};
```

please help and thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you pass a string that doesnt have the shape of an object to a JSON parse method: this could be in one of the 2 parsing methods you are using :
**Seems like youre trying to json parse a string that contains the letters *Not***

1. In this case you are assuming that the value stored in userData has this form
   `"{token:"XAXCVCDASD}"`, if the value stored it's not a **stringified object** it will fail.

```
 const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
 const userToken = JSON.parse(userData);
 const { token } = userToken.token;
```

2. In the apiFetch.js youre trying to call `res.json()`  when the response code is less than 404, but you're returning an error with status 401 on one of the responses, I believe you could be trying to call that method on a response that the content type is not on json format

```
const fetchRequest = async (url, options) => {
  try {
    const req = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}${url}`, options);
    const res = req.status <= 404 ? req : Promise.reject(req);
    return await res.json();
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`${e.message} while fetching ${url}`);
  }
};
```