# how i can find my JSON parse error inside my stripe api?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

i'm trying to figured out where my problem. i used stripe and a fake card to test my api

```
fetch(
      "https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens?card[number]=424242424242&card[exp_month]=10&card[exp_year]=2023&card[cvc]=123&amount=999&currency=usd",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          Authorization:
            "Bearer sk_test_51L6xxxxxxxx",
        },
      }
    )
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data.id));
        // HERE WE HAVE ACCESS TO THE TOKEN TO SEND IT TO OUR SERVERS
        // ALONG WITH INSENSITIVE DATA
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/buyer/payments", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
           body: JSON.stringify(data.id),
        })
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then(function (response) {
            if (response.paid) {
              // DO SOMETHING AFTER PAYMENT CONFIRMATION
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
  };
```

My function stopped always inside the catch with this error
JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Failed"

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you pass a string that doesn't have the shape of an object to a JSON parse method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840929/17627350. Most likely this line: `resp.json()` is the culprit. resp will need to be valid stringified json.